# Существует ли слово "рожусь"?

Tags: глаголы

Насколько правомерно это слово в предложении:

Когда я рожусь,... (мысли плода)

Answer (score 4):

Формальных ограничений нет. Но контекст и стиль должны быть соответствующими.

Плодом быть не обязательно. Можно просто исповедовать переселение душ.

"А если туп как дерево, // родишься баобабом" - "А когда я рожусь баобабом?"

Answer (score 1):

Оно, конечно, так. Но теоретически. А теория с практикой не всегда совпадает. Слово  любое можно образовать. Лучше сказать "появлюсь на свет"

Comment: Согласен, но вопрос поставлен "Существует ли". Я стараюсь отвечать именно на поставленные вопросы. насколько понимаю - не только я.